# What am I doing wrong here? Method Does not work

Tags: java

So I'm trying to call methods and i want it to like go from one method to another. So I at first I tried calling the method with parameters but that kind of did not work because 1 method needed more and i got confused after some errors so i tried this... I read an answer on a post and it said to try declaring variable with static outside the main method but inside the class.. So i did it

```
public class RiskGame {
//Player 1 Win
static Boolean P1Qrehz=false;
static Boolean P1Mez=false;
static Boolean P1Flehst=false;
static Boolean P1Veiled=false;
static Boolean P1Sharktooth=false;
static Boolean P1Zicat=false;
//Player 2 Win
static Boolean P2Qrehz=false;
static Boolean P2Mez=false;
static Boolean P2Flehst=false;
static Boolean P2Veiled=false;
static Boolean P2Sharktooth=false;
static Boolean P2Zicat=false;
//Stock Market
static Random stock = new Random();
static int StockCorn = stock.nextInt(433 - 350) + 350;
static int StockCotton = stock.nextInt(100 - 65) + 63;
static int StockOrange = stock.nextInt(125 - 112) + 112;
static  int StockSilver = stock.nextInt(1350 - 1000) + 1000;
static int StockSugar = stock.nextInt(500 - 200) + 200;
static int StockCoffee = stock.nextInt(400 - 300) + 300;
static int StockRice = stock.nextInt(265 - 170) + 170;
static String NameP1;
static String NameP2;
static int MoneyCount;
static int MoneyCount2;
static int CitizenLoveNum2;
static int CitizenLoveNum;
static int SoldierCount1;
static int SoldierCount2;
static String Rules;
public static void main(String[] args) {
```

And this is inside the main method

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Testing Area 
    //Player 1 Win
    //This is the Give name phase
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Welcome To RiskGame 0.1.1, This game is in Early access So expect some bugs! :)", "RiskGame 0.1.1", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "This game was originally developed and released By Elias Ioannou", "A Game By Elias Ioannou", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    String Name1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What's your name Player 1?", "Player 1");
    String Name2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What's your name Player 2?", "Player 2");
    Name1=NameP1;
    Name2=NameP2;
    //Money Setup
    String Money = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(NameP1 + ", How Much Money do you want to start with?", "1000");
    String Money2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(NameP2 + ", How Much Money do you want to start with?", "1000");
    int MoneyCountP1 = Integer.parseInt(Money);
    int MoneyCountP2 = Integer.parseInt(Money2);
    MoneyCount=MoneyCountP1;
    MoneyCount2=MoneyCountP2;
    //Rules
    String Rules1=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("This rules will add something more exciting in the game. (This rules must be done by the players). The system won't know anything so you need to play by your rules. \n Enter the custom rules you want to play with. If you want to just play the game leave it blank it won't affect anything!", "Default. No Special Rules Added");
    Rules1=Rules;
    //Soldier Count
    int SoldierCountP1 = 3;
    int SoldierCountP2 = 3;
    SoldierCount1=SoldierCountP1;
    SoldierCount2=SoldierCountP2;
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You will Both Start With " + SoldierCount1 + " Soldiers!", "Soldiers On Arms", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    //Starting City
    Random city = new Random();
    int City = city.nextInt(3 - 1) + 1;
    Random city2 = new Random();
    int City2 = city2.nextInt(3 - 1) + 1;
    int CityNum = 0;
    switch (City) {
        case 1:
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, NameP1 + ", Your Starting Island is Veiled Atoll");
            P1Veiled=true;
            CityNum = 1;
            break;
        case 2:
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, NameP1 + ", Your Starting Island is Skarktooth Isle");
            P1Sharktooth=true;
            CityNum = 2;
            break;
        case 3:
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, NameP1 + ", Your Starting Island is Zicat Peninsula");
            P1Zicat=true;
            CityNum = 3;
            break;
        default:
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Something went wrong... Try Restarting the program.");
            break;
    }
    int City2Num = 0;
    switch (City2) {
        case 1:
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, NameP2 + ", Your Starting Island is Mez Archipelago");
            P2Mez=true;
            City2Num = 1;
            break;
        case 2:
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, NameP2 + ", Your Starting Island is Flehst Archipelago");
            P2Flehst=true;
            City2Num = 2;
            break;
        case 3:
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, NameP2 + ", Your Starting Island is Qrehz Archipelago");
            P2Qrehz=true;
            City2Num = 3;
            break;
        default:
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Something went wrong... Try Restarting the program.");
            break;
    }
    //Citizen Happiness
    String CitizenLove = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(NameP1+", How Much Citizen Happiness do you want to start with?", "50");
    int CitizenLoveNumP1= Integer.parseInt(CitizenLove);
    String CitizenLove2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(NameP2+", How Much Citizen Happiness do you want to start with?", "50");
    int CitizenLoveNumP2= Integer.parseInt(CitizenLove2);
    CitizenLoveNum2=CitizenLoveNumP2;
    CitizenLoveNum=CitizenLoveNumP1;


    P2Menu();
}
```

And this is the method im trying to call but does not respond (The program exits)

```
public static void P2Menu(){
    //-CitizenLove
    Boolean Yes=true;
    while(Yes){
    CitizenLoveNum2-=15;
    }
```

What's wrong? Im new to java So please don't hate my probably bad coding skills :)

Comment: That's an infinite loop.

Comment: @frenchDolphin I have Yes=false; later on at the code so yeah it turns off later but it does not even go there to bother me

Comment: But you need to realize, `Yes=false` will never happen, because **your code won't do anything else until** `Yes=false` **.**

Comment: What do you mean by "the program exits"?

Comment: @immibis It closes. Stops Running. Idk how to explain it better than that

Comment: @frenchDolphin Oh yeah i totally forgot about that.. Anw my program kind of works now at least it goes in the P2Menu method But still am i doing something wrong on declaring the static variables above the main method?

Comment: @TakispRandomGames Ok, just making sure you weren't somehow confusing an infinite loop with an exit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To call a static method outside of the class you are in, you need to do:

```
RiskGame.P2Menu();
```

You also need to make sure that you define the `P2menu()` method inside the `RiskGame` class, like so:

```
public class RiskGame {
   ....
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ...
   P2Menu(); 
 }
public static void P2Menu(){
...
}
```

Also, you have an issue with the `P2Menu()` method, as it is in an infinite loop. You never set the variable to `false`.

Comment: It doesnt have errors but  still does not work... Em I think this might be the fault of the static declared methods or below when im trying to make them equal to the original.. please can you check the code and tell me if there is something wrong?

Comment: It's a method not a Boolean how am I suppose to said it to false?

Comment: I think you need to start with some basics. You aren't using the term `static` properly. To be honestly, I think you need to understand some of the fundamentals of OOP.

Comment: isnt static used to declare thinks publicly in class?

Comment: No, that is not what static is used for.